# Numerical integration of function - result is another function

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, indefinite-integrals

I'm new in integration and numerical integration.
As i know to calculate definite integral you can use some methods, like rects, 
trapezes, Simpson's... etc.

But is there a tool to make numerical primitive integral of function - for example to create from sinus integral a sampled (- cosinus) function?
I want to learn this and implement in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Every advanced tool to integrate differential equations has a facility to sample the solution at a given set of points. Thus integrate the differential equation $y'(t)=\sin t$ and give sample points $t=(0,0.01,0.02,...,0.99,1)$ to get a correctly numerically integrated function value table.